# How do I create a GtkApplicationWindow widget with Glade?

Tags: gtk, glade

It would be useful to me to have access to a [GtkApplicationWindow](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplicationWindow.html) object from my code, but I want to use Glade to initialise its properties.

How can I create a GtkApplicationWindow widget in Glade?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your ui xml change

```
<object class="GtkWindow" id="foo">
```

to

```
<object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="foo">
```

and after retrieving the window via gtk builder set the application property:

```
GTK_WINDOW (gtk_builder_get_object (xml, "foo"));
g_object_set(main_window, "application", application, NULL);
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, I was hoping there was a way to do it directly from the Glade editor.

Comment: @Guido Günther: how did you know that GtkApplicationWindow has an "application" property? https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplicationWindow.html doesn't say anything about it...

Comment: @MarcoScannadinari, I know this is a bit late but if you go up to the GtkWindow Parent class you will see that it has the application property as a read/write. So you just need to scan the parent classes and you will also find the functions gtk_window_get_application and gtk_window_set_application.

Admittedly, the description area for the ApplicationWindow should say something about this.